# javascript array to php array

Tags: php, ajax

i am sending data through ajax call to the php code my ajax code is this

```
    var values = JSON.stringify({ dstring: dataString, ukey:ukey });
    var page_path = server_url+"save_data.php";

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: page_path,
    cache: false,
    data: values,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){

    },
    error:function(xhr, status, error) {

    }
    });
```

and in the ajax it send data like this

```
 {"dstring":{"q2":"11","q3":"22","q4":"33","q5":"44","q6":"55"},"ukey":"1"}
```

and in the php when i try to get it through REQUEST it dont show me data , i am bit confuse on how to handle this data in php

Comment: have you tried `json_decode`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't stringify `data` on your ajax call. You should then be able to `$_POST['dstring']`on the PHP script. Also, you should add in some debug code at least into that error handler to know what's up. Last but not least, inspect the network calls.

Comment: thanks it work for me but can you please tell me why i shouldnt use stringify on alomst every example i see that its been use while sending the array .

Comment: @user1224233, that jQuery method will handle the object and make the necessary adjustments

Answer (score -1):

You have to get `file_get_contents("php://input")` and run that through `json_decode`.